# Matlab error - Attempt to extract field 'Workbooks' from 'mxArray'

Tags: excel, matlab, simulink

I try to use Simulink MATLAB Function block to run Excel macro. Below is my code:

```matlab
function duty = fcn()
duty = zeros(1,1);
coder.extrinsic('actxserver')

excel = actxserver('Excel.Application')
excel.Workbooks.Open('D:\pso.xlsm')
excel.Run('Sheet1.run_pso');
excel.Quit;

end
```

However, error come out as:

```
Attempt to extract field 'Workbooks' from 'mxArray'.
```

Anyone please help me, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the guideline before Answer a question here.

Comment: This is an clear question. A short piece of code which works in matlab but no longer when embedded in a matlab function block.

Comment: Maybe putting the whole code accessing excel into a separate m file and declaring it extrinsic works around the issue. Still I don't fully understand what's wrong.